# Expected Value of a sum of a sequence

Tags: probability

I have encountered this problem and don't know even where to start.

Let $ M = \{s_1,s_2,s_3...s_k : s_i \in \{1,...,i\}\} \subseteq \{1,...,k\}^k $

We select a sequence from M in a uniform distribution.

What is the expected value of the sum of elements in the chosen sequence?

Besides that I know that I have to define a Random Variable such that $ f(a) = sum$, I am pretty stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, it should be $(k+1)(k+2)/4$.

Comment: If a problem involves both *expectation* and *summation*, then the solution is *quite likely* to invoke the **Linearity of Expectation**.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find $E[\Sigma_{i=1}^ks_i]$. Note that, by the linearity of expectation, you have $E[\Sigma_{i=1}^ks_i] = \Sigma_{i=1}^kE[s_i]$. If $s_i$ are randomly selected, then $s_i\sim Uniform(a,b)$ and $E[s_i]=\frac{b-a}{2}$. Thus,

\begin{eqnarray*}
E[\Sigma_{i=1}^ks_i] &=& \Sigma_{i=1}^kE[s_i] \\
&=& \Sigma_{i=1}^k \frac{b-a}{2} \\
&=& \frac{k(b-a)}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}